Show items with no data is not giving expected result
I am using a Live connection to an SSAS tabular model having the following tables :
Employees : all Employees in the company
Employees VIP : Employees having the status of VIP in the company
Employees TIC : Employees having the status of TIC in the company
The relationships between the tables :
Employees - Employees VIP : 1 to many , filter in both directions based on EmpID
Employees - Employees TIC : 1 to 1 , filter in both directions based on EmpID

I am using in a visual columns from the 3 tables :
Employees : EmpID, EmpName, EmpLastName
Employees VIP : Status VIP
Employees TIC : Status TIC
I have this visual where I use data from Employees and Employees TIC :

When I try to add for the previous visual, columns from Employees VIP :

Now I want to show all the Employees, either they belong or not to any VIP or TIC so I selected Show items with no data :

When I try to change the order of the Staus VIP to be before Status TIC :
The display of data changes for the Employees E,F, G and H, I can"t understand this behaviour :

Link to the file : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1-rk-VKwYrGdbY7q_cjk_3TlBbAtH3U-H?usp=sharing

I think the answer to this is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-show-items-no-data

It's important to note that the mechanism of selecting values for the
columns is order-dependent, and can be thought of as a Left outer join
operation between tables. If the order of the columns is changed, the
results change as well.


Can you change this below table relation to "one-to-one" and check?


If I do that it works, but I cannot change it in the real model
